# loading gltf file in nextjs using 'react-3d-viewer'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gltf

I am trying to load a gltf file in nextjs react using npm 'react-3d-viewer'.The gltf file is coming from database.

```
   import {GLTFModel,AmbientLight,DirectionLight} from 'react-3d-viewer'
    import React, { Suspense } from "react";
    import getConfig from "next/config";
    import axios from "axios";
    const config = getConfig();
    class ModalDemo extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
                filePath: '',
            };
    
    
        }
     
    
        render() {
    
            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div>
                        <p>okay</p>
                          <GLTFModel
                    src={this.state.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visitImageRequirementInfo/getImageByImagePathId?imagePath=' + this.state.filePath}>
                    <AmbientLight color={0xffffff}/>
                    <DirectionLight color={0xffffff} position={{x:100,y:200,z:100}}/>
                    <DirectionLight color={0xff00ff} position={{x:-100,y:200,z:-100}}/>
                </GLTFModel>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default ModalDemo;
```

The filePath attribute contains the value of gltf which has the value like this

> visitImageDirectory/4f2f0f63-e57b-4eb8-b3d5-c4a2413cd2bd.gltf

and its coming by get request in the componetDidMount function from database .All i am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

This is my next.config.js file if it has anything to do with it

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withCSS, { cssModules: true  }],
    [withImages],
], {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {   serverRuntimeConfigValue: 'test server'  },
    // publicRuntimeConfig: {   publicRuntimeConfigValue: {apiUrl:'http://127.0.0.1:5000'} },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {   publicRuntimeConfigValue: {apiUrl:process.env.apiUrl.trim()} },
    webpack: (config, options) => {   return config;   } ,exportTrailingSlash: true
});
```

How can i resolve this issue. or any other library i can use to show the gltf file is nextjs from database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because the library is accessing window property on server, as Next.js Renders components Server side. So the best thing you can do here (if you don't mind server side benefits for this particular component) is using **dynamic imports with `ssr: false`**.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';


const AmbientLight = dynamic(() =>
  import('react-3d-viewer').then((mod) => mod.AmbientLight),{ssr: false}
)

const GLTFModel = dynamic(() =>
  import('react-3d-viewer').then((mod) => mod.GLTFModel),{ssr: false}
)

const DirectionLight = dynamic(() =>
  import('react-3d-viewer').then((mod) => mod.DirectionLight),{ssr: false}
)
```

Comment: after your solution now i am getting this error
`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of ModalDemo.`